# Permissions and performance issues using Windows 11 + WSL2 (Ubuntu), Docker Desktop & WordPress via docker-compose local environment

Tags: wordpress, docker-compose, permissions, wsl-2, windows-11

I am working on a project handed over by a previous developer which utilises docker desktop and a docker-compose.yml file to bring up a WordPress project on my Windows PC. This worked okay on my last PC (Windows 10), I've now upgraded to a new PC running on Windows 11.

The project worked fine with a non WSL version of docker, just using hyper-v and docker-compose with some mounted volumes to create the containers and code up a bespoke WordPress theme (running on roots/sage 8).

Since moving to Windows 11, the project has been almost unusable due to massively slow pagespeed (30 seconds minimum to load just about anything).

I tried to solve this by switching to WSL2. I followed tutorials from Microsoft & Docker to get WSL2 setup with Ubuntu.

I did a totally clean install of:

- WSL2
- Ubuntu
- Docker Desktop
- VS Code

My understanding is that adding the project files directly into Ubuntu is the best way to go as it should be a lot faster than trying to mount the files from Windows, so I setup SSH keys and cloned the repo into my `/home/andy/` directory.

Running `docker-compose up` successfully fires up the website but I then get hit with loads of issues I never encountered while running the project via docker desktop without WSL2.

- WordPress or the web user seems to be lacking permissions to write to the `wp-content` directory
  -- Can't install any plugins
  -- Can't upload media
- VS code (launched via `code .` in the project directory) doesn't have permission to write to anywhere in `wp-content`
- FileZilla is unable to create any folders within `wp-content` including in `wp-content/uploads`

I need to get this project working, I'm obviously not a docker or linux expert, I just need to get it fired up so I can continue coding with WordPress!

I've trawled through most pages of Google's search results for people having similar issues and I've done a fresh install of the WSL2/Docker setup multiple times after trying different things to get this to work but nothing is working.

I've tried:

- adding to the docker-entrypoint.sh `chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html`
  -- This was to try and give the www-data user ownership of everything mounted into the `var/www/html` directory, which appeared initially to help but broke other permissions, like Filezilla being able to write to `wp-content`
- Ensured that all the directories/files in my project folder had the correct permissions for WordPress `755` for directories & `644` for files
  -- Had no effect on the issue
- Attempted to set `777` recursively on the entire project directory in Ubuntu
  -- Still had issues with FileZilla & VS Code, and for some reason, when I did `docker-compose up` the permissions on `wp-content` reset themselves from `777` to `755`
- Added `user:$USER` within the `wordpress` part of the `docker-compose.yml` file, and then did `USER=root docker-compose up`
  -- This appeared to give WordPress the permissions/access needed in order to write to `wp-content` as I could now download and install plugins, and upload media, but the entire backend of WordPress was very slow and I still couldn't save files with VS code, or download with FileZilla.
- Attempted to take ownership of the `/home/andy` directory where my project files live via `sudo chown -R andy /home/andy/`
  -- This allowed VS Code & FileZilla to both work as expected, saving files and downloading files from a remote server into Ubuntu via WSL2

With weird root user hacky solution + chown on the user directory, I appeared to have got everything "working", but wp-admin was so ridiculously slow, it was barely usable.

Another post I came across said that using `.local` to access the site was a bad idea since that could cause slow performance with docker, so I then changed the website url in my hosts file, and did a find and replace on the DB/Files to reflect the change, and now the backend of WordPress works fast, but appears to have permissions issues as lots of plugins are complaining about not having the correct permissions and I'm unable to download / install or even deactivate existing plugins.

I'm basically at a total loss at this point as for how to get this working. If anyone has any suggestions I'd be very grateful.

Thanks!